# Adding same prefab to a game scene will or not increase draw calls?

Tags: unity-game-engine, cocos2d-x

It comes to me that when I keep adding a same prefab to one scene, the draw calls keep increasing. Can I do Something to make it lower?

Comment: I believe this question belongs to gamedev.stackexchange.com, but I cannot flag for migration to that site

Comment: @Nadir Game Dev is *primarily* for non-programming game design topics (e.g. "What are some ways to keep the player engaged in an endless game?" or "Pros and cons of randomised item stats?"). While programming questions *related to game development* will be answered there, such questions would still be acceptable on SO as well.

Comment: Blake: prefabs in no way insure that draw calls will be kept in check. There are multiple reasons for draw calls to increase, including complex shaders or real time lights.

Answer (score 1):

To reduce draw calls you can use different technics and which technic you use really depends on the type of game you create and targeted platform.

Some ways to reduce draw calls:

- Occlusion Culling
- Batching
- GPU instancing

For more information please read Unity3D documentation on [Optimizing graphics rendering in Unity games](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/temas/performance-optimization/optimizing-graphics-rendering-unity-games?playlist=44069)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way of reducing draw calls while keeping the same assets is to use merging, where you create a single mesh from various meshes. This will increase the the video memory, as you will have to replicate all meshes data.

Another approach, more complex and which requires you to write your own shaders is to use instance-merging, where you create a single asset from various meshes and draw it by using the vertices to fetch the required data, allowing you to draw multiple assets as a single mesh (1 draw call) without replicating data.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to reduce draw calls, and optimize.

1. Using Atlas/Spritesheet. Renderers that uses Sprites from the same atlas can help reduce draw calls especially if the layering of game objects are done right.
2. You can use Unity's Frame Debugger to know if you can still optimize the prefabs/game objects based on the layering/hierarchy. [Frame Debugger](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/FrameDebugger.html)
3. Proper use of Canvas. For the UI part of the game, if there are sliders, animating windows, moving objects on the UI, it is best to have them on a separate Canvas. The reason for this is because if the RectTransform of a UI changes, the entire Canvas is drawn. So if 80% of the UI did not change, but they are on the same canvas from the 20% that did change, the 80% will still be redrawn.